# Verify if plaidml is using gpu

Tags: keras, plaidml

I have installed plaidml-keras and configured it to use my local GPU.

However, within a python script, is there anyway I can verify my plaidml keras backend is using GPU and not CPU?

Comment: did you ever find out the answer to this question?

Comment: Nope. Anyways, my script (training of the model) was failing when I was configuring to use my local GPU. So I was not able to continue with my local GPU. @SamVanhoutte

Answer (score 0):

you can verify it by observing the change in gpu usage in task manager

Comment: Probably yes, but he wants to do it from within a python script